# Looking for proof that $R[x,y]/(f)$ formally smooth over R implies that $(f, \partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)=1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. An $R$-algebra $A$ is *formally smooth* over R if for all $R$-algebras $B$ with ideals $I \subset B, I^2=0$, if there is a surjection from Hom$_{R-alg}(A, B)$ to Hom$_{R-alg}(A, B/I)$.

Now, one can show that if $A = R[x,y]/(f)$ for $f \in R[x,y]$ and $(f, \partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)=1$, then $A$ is formally smooth over $R$.

My question is about the converse:

> If $A$ as above is formally smooth over $R$, then $(f, \partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)=1$.

Is it possible to prove the converse via a judicious choice of $B$ and $I$, or must one use more technical tools to prove it?

Comment: Consider B=A[t]/(t^2)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for the hint! I thought of using that ring before, but it seems like there is always a map from A to its dual numbers, so I wouldn't be using the smoothness? Or is the idea to lift the identity map on A to something involving (t^2) and using Taylor's theorem in some way?

Comment: What I really meant was: if $A=R[x,y]/(f(x,y))$, consider $B=R[x,y,s,t]/(f(x+s,y+t), s^2,st,t^2)$. What I wrote above does not help at all :-)

Comment: There is now an answer to a duplicate of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528668/does-formal-smoothness-of-r-to-rx-y-f-imply-f-f-x-f-y-rx-y/2653658#2653658).